# не могу записать файл, python

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

```
with open('text.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('hello')
```

при попытке запуска с помощью visual studio code не записывается файл, а если открою файл через cmd то запись пройдет успешно. Может это из-за расширений? Установленные расширения: C#, Debugger for Unity, gdscript, godot-tools, Jupyter, Kotlin, Mono Debug, Python, Russian Language pack, Tabnine AI AutoComplete, Unity Tools, Visual Studio IntelliCode.

Comment: Может он записывается не туда, куда вы ожидаете?

Comment: Стопудов файл лежит в этой папке: `import os.path; print(os.path.abspath('.'))`

Comment: Распечатайте [os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) чтобы узнать куда попадает ваш файл.

Comment: ничего не работает

Comment: Да ну так не может быть ;)